# Using COMtypes Python module on different computer throws Exception

Tags: python-3.x, comtypes

Python 3.4.
I am using 32bit. The computer in question also runs microsoft word 32bit.

I am creating a program that reads .MPF files(some sort of Microsoft word document) and parses information.

EDIT:

I was able to re-create the issue using only (3) lines of code, using a test program.

```
import comtypes.client

print("Creating COMtypes...")
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
print("Opening word document...")
doc = word.Documents.Open('C:/1087981_18699245.MPF')
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
print("Test is success!")
```

I am still getting the same error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "OpenMPFDoc.py", line 4, in <module>
    File "C:\Python34x86\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    File "C:\Python34x86\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    File "C:\Python34x86\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 112, in GetBestInterface
AttributeError: 'module' object as no attribute '_Application'
```

This program works perfectly on my work computer, but gives this error on the destination computer.

Comment: Is that exception raised only when tkinter is involved? If not, then a [mcve] without tkinter related code would be appropriate, and no [tag:tkinter] tag.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly the same problem as Kevin right now. In my case I'm using pyinstaller to convert the app to an exe file, add it to the context menu of Windows and execute my programm with a docx file as input. Maybe this isn't necessary to know for this bug, because for me the error is also when calling CreateObject('Word.Application').